Does Qt use pkg-config
Does Qt use pkg-config?
If not, what is the best way to find where Qt is installed for the Automake & friends project?
My project is based on the Autotools and Makefile is generated by Anjuta.
There are bunch of results on Google, however I can't find one that will really help. So hopefully this will be one for everybody.
Also - don't answer like You should switch to CMake or Qmake. I have a big code base that builds perfectly with GTK+, except I am trying to incorporate some Qt specific functionality. (Project itself is wxWidgets-based).
EDIT:
This is my binary Makefile.am:
## Process this file with automake to produce Makefile.in

bin_PROGRAMS =  \
    dbhandler

dbhandler_SOURCES =  \
    doc.cpp \
    doc.h \
    docview.cpp \
    docview.h \
    mainframe.cpp \
    mainframe.h \
    view.cpp \
    view.h \
    viewbase.cpp \
    viewbase.h \
    newtablehandler.cpp \
    newtablehandler.h \
    query.h \
    table.h

dbhandler_CXXFLAGS = -I../../dbinterface \
    -I../../libdbwindow/res/gui \
    `wx-config --cxxflags` 

dbhandler_LDFLAGS = `wx-config --libs` 

As you can see it is presumes that wxWidgets becomes installed after building and it uses internally either GTK or Qt on *nix. Now here is the Makefile.am where the font panel is:
lib_LTLIBRARIES =  \
    libpropertypages.la

libpropertypages_la_SOURCES =  \
    qt/fontpropertypageQt.cpp \
    qt/fontpropertypageQt.h \
    gtk/fontpropertypageGTK.cpp \
    gtk/fontpropertypageGTK.h

libpropertypages_la_CXXFLAGS = -I../../dbinterface \
    `pkg-config \
    --cflags \
    gtk+-3.0` \
    `wx-config --cxxflags`

libpropertypages_la_LDFLAGS = `pkg-config \
    --libs \
    gtk+-3.0` \
    `wx-config --libs`

With GTK it compiles fine. With Qt its not because it needs to find QFontPanerl/QFontDialog.
After more deep searching I find I should be using QMake to identify where Qt installs headers/libraries. But if I don't have Qt installed and no QMake, I will not be able to do anything.
EDIT:
Based on this, I think I need to do the following:
In configure.ac:
# Check for Qt libraries
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(QT, [QtCore, QtGui, QtNetwork], [], [AC_MSG_ERROR([Qt libraries are required.])])
AX_HAVE_QT()
if test -z have_qt == "yes"
    USE_QT = 1
elif
    USE_QT = 0
fi

Then in Makefile.am:
if test -z USE_QT == 1
    libpropertypages_la_CXXFLAGS = -I../../dbinterface \
`wx-config --cxxflags` $(QT_CXXFLAGS) $(QT_LIBS)
elif
    libpropertypages_la_CXXFLAGS = -I../../dbinterface `pkg-config \
--cflags \
gtk+-3.0` \
`wx-config --cxxflags`
fi


OT: a project based on wxWidgets, built "with Gtk+" (?) and using Qt functionalities seems the perfect recipe for a possible disaster. Which, coincidentally, it's exactly what has already been suggested in a comment to a quite similar question you asked before.

@musicamante, well if you are being careful - it is not. wx do not provide cross-platform functionality I need and so I'm trying to implement it myself.

BTW, it is based on wxWidgets, but will have files based on functionality of GTK, QT and OSX  for one specific thing I need. Dint see an issue here.

Unless the program specifically needs to use the other libraries due to its very nature, I don't really see the point in making the effort of providing support for such different toolkits (including the care about avoiding collisions). If you aim for cross platform compliance, Qt is by far the most easy to use among them (Gtk may too to some extent, but it's known for being more *nix centric; not considering its inconsistencies and generally poor documentation). What is that specific "cross-platform functionality" you need that no other toolkit provides for all OS it supports?

@musicamante, that was not my question's answer but I'll explain anyway. I need a font property page - not a font dialog for font selection. Font panel that I can place on the notebook and use it to choose font as one of the option in a set. Now Qt is ugly and wxWidgets outruns it any date/time, but we are here NOT to start the flame war, right? I just need to find where Qt installs the jheaders and libraries, so I can use it.

Now for GTK I am using pkg-config --cflags --libs. But I can't use the same for Qt - there is no support for that. However, I think there is some qt-specific script that will allow me to find where the headers and libraries are for qt. What is it?

As said, my comment was OT :-) But consider that we know nothing about your program, needs or experience, so we can only make assumptions based on what we read. Too often we get questions from people trying to make their way using incompatible toolkits, and most of the times it's because of their lack of experience or knowledge (it may not be the case for C++, due to the implicit knowledge it requires, but, still). Now, if your "ugly" point was about QFontDialog, that's a bit irrelevant (also considering that it uses the OS dialog by default). If you want to display a custom window/dialog »

» showing font properties, then Qt certainly allows that. It may require some time to properly implement it from scratch (depending on your experience), but it also provides lots of extensibility. For instance, the image I used in this post (probably showing more than you may need) was created completely in Qt, and dynamically; I only run it on my platform, but I'm sure that it would have also worked as expected in any other OS and with any given font, showing those sizes accordingly. Still, we're OT, and I'll stop here. If you want, we can continue in chat.

@musicamante, all this is good, but you still didn't answer my question - how do I identify the qt headers/libraries directory.. As said - for GTK it is easy. You run pkg-config --cflags --libs. For Qt you can't run pkg-config, because Qt, just like wxWxidgets has their own way of identifying this.

Also, please see my edit for the OP.

And finally - an official Qt documentation from https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/linux-building.html#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20Qt%20is%20configured,configure%20options%20to%20tweak%20further. is not helpful. It only explains how to work with 1 IDE and don't say how to work with different paths where Qt could be installed...

Sorry, I cannot answer your question, I don't actually use C++ for development, as I always write with its Python bindings (and even if I would, I'd probably look for a Qt-only based solution anyway). The reason for which the Qt docs don't explain other approaches is probably because providing such information for all the possible combinations of doing it with external toolkits would be a pointless effort on their part, not to mention the fact that, for obvious reasons, they try to "force" developers to only use Qt ;-) Maybe consider writing to the Qt forums.


Does Qt use pkg-config?

You seem to be asking whether Qt provides pkg-config data.  Yes, it does.
In typical Qt form, it provides several pkg-config files, one general one, and one for each major Qt subsystem (Core, Gui, Widgets, etc).  Given that you need to have a Qt development environment installed to work on a project such as you describe, you could have discovered this for yourself.
However, as for

what is the best way to find where Qt is installed for the Automake & friends project?

, I would suggest the AX_HAVE_QT macro from the Autoconf archive.  That is much better aligned with and idiomatic for an Autotools project.  Also, it gives you more information, including the paths to several Qt development tools, for example.

After more deep searching I find I should be using QMake to identify
where Qt installs headers/libraries. But if I don't have Qt installed
and no QMake, I will not be able to do anything.

If your project depends on Qt then you need Qt to build it, so I don't follow why you think there's an issue with relying on qmake for the wanted checks.
In this regard, it is relevant that AX_HAVE_QT does use qmake to perform its job.  However, if your Qt dependency is optional, or if in some other way you can have a sensible project build without Qt, then this is one of the main reasons why you should detect Qt at configuration time instead of at build time, which this macro will do for you.  If Qt is in some way optional, then that gives you a way to configure the build appropriately for Qt's absence.  If not, then it can tell you right away that Qt is missing, instead of the build failing somewhere in the middle.
Similar applies to detecting and configuring for other packages too, by the way.  For example, this ...

dbhandler_LDFLAGS = `wx-config --libs`


is both abominable and wrong.  It is abominable at least because the needed libraries and flags should be determined at configuration time, not build time.  It is wrong because *_LDFLAGS is the wrong place to list libraries that need to be included in the link.  They should go in LDADD or *_LDADD for program targets, or in LIBADD or *_LIBADD for library targets.  Using LDFLAGS puts them in the wrong place in the link command line.

I'm not really familiar with writing the configure/makefile myself. In stead I rely on the IDE (Anjuta in my case) to do that for me. I will try to make some code in the configure, but it will be the trial and error, unfortunately. I will update this thread with more if I don't succeed. Thx.

I just made the edit to the OP. Could you please look at it and see if that is correct? Thx.

@Igor, I am confident that if you had actually tried that then you would have discovered that it does not work. In fact, there are too many things wrong with it to cover in a comment, which is anyway diverging from the question posed.  And speaking of the question posed, do be aware that around here we do not look kindly on edits that change the nature of the question or significantly expand its scope after answers have already been written. Not that you've necessarily done that.

but the idea is correct, right? Check the presene with the macro in configure and then set some variable. And then in Makefile check that variable and modify the flags accordingly. Or even conceptually it is wrong?

@Igor, the general idea is right, but you should be looking into Automake conditionals which have different syntax than shell variables and shell logical tests do.  But where you can do, I recommend avoiding conditional code in (auto)makefiles altogether.  Sometimes you can do without by setting the values of your config's output variables appropriately.  For example, if you make QT_CXXFLAGS and QT_LIBS empty when Qt is unavailable then you can reference them unconditionally on the Automake side.

making them empty make sense. Now unfortunately https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_have_qt.html, doesn't give the full syntax of the macro. I guess the syntax is well known for people who continuosly writes the Makefile or people who work on IDEs, but not for noobs like me. Can you help?

Well yes, @Igor, the web page does give the full syntax of the macro.  It's in the "Synopsis" section at the top.  Perhaps you're confused by the fact that it's so simple. From the description section, you can learn that it works by finding qmake in the path, and extracting all the other information from that.  The only caveat, then, is that you need qmake to be in the path.

OK, lets discuss it on my other question...
